# Pyshark does not capture any packet

Tags: python, networking, pyshark

Hi I'm trying to sniff network with pyshark. I just want to capture the packet but pyshark does not capture any packet

Hi is the basic code and result

```
>>> cap = pyshark.LiveCapture(interface="wlan0")
>>> cap.sniff(timeout=20)
>>> cap
<LiveCapture (0 packets)>
```

Please help

Comment: You can try enabling debug mode with `cap.set_debug(True)` before your call to `cap.sniff()`. This might give you some more information.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35985296/pyshark-can-not-capture-the-packet-on-windows-7-python/54064844#54064844 check this if this might solve your error.

Answer (score 2):

Are you using windows 10? 
it may be late but the LiveCapture feature of pyshark 3.7.9 has some problems in windows 10.

You can roll back to pyshark 0.3.6.2 with,
`pip install pyshark==0.3.6.2`